# HTML.ActionLink redirect not stopping with return false in $.ajax()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, html.actionlink

i've a `HTML.ActionLink` on view. what i'm doing is i'm making call to `$.ajax()` function which checks for return true or false from an `anction`. it hitting the action, returning the desired result true/false. but the problem is when it returns false. i need to show an `alert` and redirect should be only in case if its return true..

**ActionLink:**

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Add Race", "AddRace",
     new {eventId = Model.EventId, fleetId=Model.SelectedFleet.ID}, 
          new{onclick="return checkFleetAddedandScroing()"}) %>
```

**Function:**

```
 function checkFleetAddedandScroing() {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '<%=Url.Action("CheckFleetExists", new {eventId=Model.EventId})%>',
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                data = eval("(" + data + ")");
                if (data == true) {
                    alert('Ok button clicked');
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Cannot delete this fleet becasue either you have already added races to this event or the fleet has used for boat registration.");
                    return false;
                }
            }, //success
            error: function (req) {

            }
        });
    }
```

it redirects always..whether it returns true/false..it should redirect only if it returns true....

Please correct me where i'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning false from the AJAX callback.

That has nothing to do with the return value from the outer function; the AJAX callback won't even start running until later.

Comment: can you explain it a bit more please, i'm pretty new to MVC..and what i need to do to achieve my requirement with my current approact..

Comment: @MayankPathak your problem is clear.i have posted an answer for this problem and it seems you got no more options other than this.

Answer (score 1):

you must wait for your request to receive the result, and for doing this set async parameter of ajax function to false.

**EDIT:** you are lucky with your scenario. you can always return false and in case of successful delete call a function named `DoRedirect`.

this is the way to go :

```
function checkFleetAddedandScroing() {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '<%=Url.Action("CheckFleetExists", new {eventId=Model.EventId})%>',
            dataType: "json",        
            timeout: 30000,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                data = eval("(" + data + ")");
                if (data == true) {
                    alert('Ok button clicked'); 
                    DoRedirect();
                }
                else {
                    alert("Cannot delete this fleet becasue either you have already added races to this event or the fleet has used for boat registration.");
                }
            }, //success
            error: function (req) {

            }
        });
        return false;
    }

  function DoRedirect(){
        //code for do redirect
  }
```

cheers!